# update query to update two fields in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to update two fields in laravel 5.3.I have two fields values 'status_id' and 'comment'.my query is working is I update only 'status_id' field

```
  DB::table('travel_request')
        ->where('id',$id )
        ->update(['status_id' => DB::table('travel_request_status')->where('status', $status)->first()->id]);
```

I tried to update two fields as follows

```
DB::table('travel_request')
        ->where('id',$id )
        ->update(['status_id' => DB::table('travel_request_status')->where('status', $status)->first()->id],['comment'=>$comment]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing two arrays, but you should pass one array with two `key => value` pairs as parameter:

```
DB::table('travel_request')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->update([
        'status_id' => DB::table('travel_request_status')->where('status', $status)->first()->id,
        'comment' => $comment
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

All fields should be in one array.

> According to Laravel Documentation, The update method expects an array
>   of column and value pairs representing the columns that should be
>   updated.

Try

```
DB::table('travel_request')
        ->where('id',$id )
        ->update(['status_id' => DB::table('travel_request_status')->where('status', $status)->first()->id, 'comment'=>$comment]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you put closure in wrong place

```
DB::table('travel_request')
        ->where('id',$id )
        ->update(['status_id' => 
                      DB::table('travel_request_status')->where('status', $status)->first()->id
                 ,'comment'=>$comment]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a small change.

```
DB::table('travel_request')
->where('id',$id )
->update(['status_id' => DB::table('travel_request_status')->where('status', $status)->first()->id,'comment' => $comment
]);
```